# Javascript and HTML form validation checks

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms

i am trying to learn html and javascript. I have created an html form and am using javascript to validate the fields. I have a isNaN check for the age field, a regex check for emial and a presence check for all fields. I am currently outputting the form to the address bar but this does not work as i am getting errors.

```
<title> </title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate()
    {
        var errors = 0;
        if (isNumeric(document.getElementById("age").value) == false)
        {
            errors++;
        }
        if (emailCheck(document.getElementById("email").value) == false)
        {
            errors++;
        }
        var inputBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(var i= 0; i < inputBoxes.length; i++)
        {
            if(inputBoxes[i].type != 'text') continue;
            if(presenceCheck(inputBoxes[i].value) == false)
            {
                errors++;

            }
        }
        console.log(errors);
        if(errors == 0)
        {
        window.location.assign("output.html#" + "%%" + "name" + "%%" + 
        document.getElementById("name").value + "%%" + "email" + "%%" +
        document.getElementById("email").value + "%%" + "age" + "%%" +
        document.getElementById("age").value + "%%" + "comments" + "%%" + 
        document.getElementById("comments").value);
        }
    }
    function isNumeric(number)
    {
        return !isNaN(number) && number != null && number != "";
    }
    function emailCheck(email)
    {
        var emailRegex = /\s+@\s+.\s+/;
        return emailRegex.test(email);
    }
    function presenceCheck(data)
    {
        var regex = /\s+/;
        return regex.test(data);
    }

</script>
```

Below is the form which is just incased in body tags at the moment

```
<form id="frmA" name="frmA">
    <label name="frmName">Name:</label><br />
    <input form="frmA" type="text" name="frmName" id="name"/><br />
    <label name="frmEmail">E-Mail:</label><br />
    <input form="frmA" type="text" name="frmEmail" id="email"/><br />
    <label name="age">Age:</label><br />
    <input form="frmA" name="frmAge" id="age"/><br />
    <label name="frmComments">Comments:</label><br />
    <textarea form="frmA" cols="50" rows="10" id="comments"></textarea><br />
</form>
    <button onClick="validate();">Submit</button>
```

i know that the checks work when no data is present however when i input data in the form and hit submit i am still faced with 4 errors. (there are 5 errors with no data: 3x presence checks, 1 for the regex and one for the isNaN)

My question therefore is why am i still getting errors and why do i get no output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Extra: i would also like the input fields to change colour when there is an error.

Comment: May I recommend, if its possible depending on your supported browsers, that you use HTML5s built in validation checks, such as : `<input type="email"../>` etc

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question here?

Comment: Sorry that i wasnt clear, the question is why am i still getting errors and why do i not get any output. I have updated the main post with this too.

Comment: RE: using html5s built in check. I am trying to learn html and javascript so i want to learn the difficult way and then when i am proficient, i'll use shorcuts and built in help. :)

Comment: In that case you may want to expand on you email regex as it isn't accurate

Comment: Do you know about the javascript console (f12 in chrome). What errors are you getting? Why are you outputting to the address bar?

Comment: When run, the javascript outputs a number based on the errors in the form (e.g. if a field is blank, it outputs an error). I know that the age check works but i dont know about the others and i dont know how to fix them. Telling me i need to expand my email regex is all well and good but i dont know how so help would be appreciated.  i am outputting to the address bar as a temporary solution whilst i work on getting the check correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexes are wrong. You have `/\s+@\s+.\s+/` and it should be `/\w+@\w+\.\w+/`. You didn't escape the dot and `\s` matches whitespace, not strings. `\w` matches word. For a proper email regex you would need much more than that but for your simple case to work this will suffice. The second regex should be `/\w+/`.

Comment: Thank you! I changed these and the code works fine now. I also implemented a different output method which now work ok.